# php, linux Is is possible to prevent to echo content of file located outside webroot?

Tags: php, mysql

Possibly all below is not reasonable, but want to make clear and understand.

Aim is protect email addresses and phone numbers, recorded in mysql. If hacker get database, to make it more difficult to get real emails

Decided to do it like this

1) outside webroot place some text file

2) in php `$content_of_some_file = include '/wamp/some_file.txt';`

3) `INSERT into users (email) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('someemail@example.com', $content_of_some_file));`

But if hacker can access to mysql, no problems to get access to php files and use `echo $content_of_some_file;`. Get key and `SELECT AES_DECRYPT(email, 'key')`

Any ideas how to prevent it? Is it possible at all? If not possible, then all above is almost unreasonable...

Aim is following:

1) visitors from website want to send message to some user

2) visitor types message in input field, clicks send

3) i take user's email from mysql and send the message to the email

Want to prevent:

Hacker get content of mysql and want to take emails to send spam (instead of actual emails hacker see something not understandable). Hacker wants to convert to actual emails.

Hacker also gets access to php files. In one of php files hacker inserts code to see `$content_of_some_file` (a key placed outside webroot).

Using the key, hacker `AES_DECRYPT` and get actual emails.

Is it possible not to allow hacker to see `$content_of_some_file` (a key placed outside webroot)?

Tried to use php `DEFINE`

If in file outside webroot insert `define("GREETING","Hello you! How are you today?");`

And in file inside webroot insert only `echo constant("GREETING");`
I can see content of constant `GREETING`. So, if hacker inserts such code, he can see content of key for `AES_DECRYPT` and decrypt emails.

Seems must set php files (directories) not writable... Hacker could not insert code and could not upload files. And could not directly access to file located outside webroot. It would be some measure...

And seems also need obfuscate part of php code so that from code hacker can not know variable and file names.

Comment: If you can change the way in which the email field is handled (e.g. if you need to send email to it) you could encrypt it with the user's password. That means it won't be accessible to anyone (including you) until the user signs in. That would be very high security, but has disadvantages too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If contents of some file is just a salt as it seems above, you could just use a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) (a random collection of characters) located anywhere.

That way, the hacker in question would have to be in your PHP code as well as having database access. In terms of actual usage; the salt would have to have some kind of reference if using a list.

```
define('SALT', 'iuoerghiuowerbnfcuioq3hrj980127yu589734754-12j84903q24fyjrm03qwy4ruw');
INSERT into users (email) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('someemail@example.com', SALT));
```

As salt is an unchanging password, the entry in mysql can be returned to a readable for using AES_DECRYPT along with the salt using

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(email, SALT)
    WHERE user_id = 'recipient_id'
    FROM users
    Limit 1;
```

Do note that in both these cases you will need to escape the mysql string in order to insert the actual salt as a password, otherwise you will literally be using SALT as the password.

The other alternative is to use a ready made class such as the one found [here](https://github.com/philios33/PHP-AES-File-Encryption) which will allow you to encode the entry from within PHP completely ignoring the database.

**Update to reflect holding salt outside of web root**

In order to allow PHP to access paths outside of the web root, you will need to look up the [basedir directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir). For example:

```
open_basedir = /srv/http/:/path/to/where/you/keep/salt/
```

This declares both the web_root and another path as being accessable by PHP, note the semi-colon in between. Now, you create a file in that path with your salt:

```
/path/to/where/you/keep/salt/salt.php
<?php $strSalt = 'hideouslylongandobscurestring'; ?>
```

With that set, where you intend to use the code, instead of a define as used earlier, replace with the following:

```
include('/path/to/where/you/keep/salt/salt.php');
INSERT into users (email) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('someemail@example.com', $strSalt));
```

However, if the hacker in question has access to your files they can simply find this include and extract the salt. There's really no simple panacea (cure all) if both your database and host get compromised.

If certain you need something a little more foolproof and willing to go to extremes, you're really looking at a setup where you have the salt generated offsite (based on user account criteria) and delivered through secure means by something like OAuth for the authorisation part. At this point, you're really starting to make life difficult for yourself when you just want to encrypt an email address though and going beyond the scope of this question.

Hope this food for thought helps

Comment: I need actual email. For example some visitor visits website and wants to send message to some user. Visitor writes content of the message, clicks Send. Ajax process get actual email and sends to user. If random SALT, could i latter get actual email?

Comment: 1) outside webroot i `define('SALT', 'iuoe...');` 2) hacker get access to php files in webroot. 3) in some php file hacker inserts something like `echo SALT...` to see `iuoe...`. Or it would not be possible? (i have very little knowledge about `DEFINE`)

Comment: @user2118559 - In order for PHP to be capable of reading the salt, if storing the salt outside of the web path, you will need to look up basedir. I've updated the answer to include some links on this. However, PHP will still be able to read these directories so, in theory the salt will be accessable regardles.
Define - Refers to a variable type called constant. So long as already declared, these variables will be available anywhere within the code. I can understand your desire seeking security through obscurity. See updated answer

Comment: My idea regarding seeking security through obscurity if following. Hacker get database with emails like `¶jÄÊ¥`. Hacker need actual email. He knows that i use `AES_ENCRYPT`. He need salt or key. He can not access file outside webroot (as i understand). So one way how to get salt displayed is `echo/print` variable where salt is included. It would be good to make impossible to know variable name. Such is my idea.

Comment: Being a process within a machine, PHP will need a point of reference to the salt at some point. See my updated answer final paragraph, food for thought when taking things to the extreme

Comment: If salt located outside webroot (salt included as variable, like $salt) and hacker can not access to files outside webroot, then the only way as i understand hacker must modify code like `echo $salt`, to see salt and latter to use to decrypt email addresses. To prevent this as i understand, must set readonly to all directories. So hacker could not modify content of files and instead of actual salt would see `$salt`